# Tex error when I run my tex file

Tags: math-mode

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \subequations already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

! LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

! Undefined control sequence.
```

I got the above 3 errors when I run my tex file. Would you please help me in this regard.

Here is my TeX file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The layout of this document is based on current (August 2006)       %
% Graduate studies guidelines for thesis submission.                  %
% http://umanitoba.ca/faculties/graduate_studies/registration/137.htm %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% This template support both bibliographies and indices.
% The correct sequence to build the final output file is:
% (1) (pdf)latex
% (2) bibtex
% (3) makeindex
% (4) (pdf)latex
% (5) (pdf)latex
%
%
% I recommend that content chapters be split off into seperate files,
%   which are then accessed by (e.g.) \input{chapter1.tex}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PAGE SETUP PACKAGES... order is significant. %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\usepackage[letterpaper,includeall,
            vmargin={1in,1in},
            hmargin={1.5in,0.375in}
            ]{geometry}


 \usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{natbib}



\usepackage[letterpaper,
            colorlinks=true,
            pdfpagemode=UseNone,
            urlcolor=blue,
            bookmarks=true,
            backref=page,
%            plainpages=false
            ]{hyperref}


 % Use only one of the following:
%   linespread effects math mode, openup does not.
%\linespread{1.6}    % 1.3 = line and a half spacing; 1.6 = double spaced
\openup4\jot        % 1 = single; 2.5 = line and half; 4 = double

\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
 \setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% make backreferences look nice:
% ftp://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/backref.pdf
%\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}
%\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
%   \ifcase #1 %
%        (Not cited.)%
%    \or
%       (Cited on page~#2.)%
%    \else
%        (Cited on pages~#2.)%
%    \fi}
%\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
%\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ and~}
%\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{ and~}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\usepackage{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{makeidx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cases}
%\documentstyle[a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{amssymb,verbatim,latexsym}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\newcommand{\freq}[1]{\begin{displaymath} #1 \end{displaymath}}
%\newcommand{\mfont}[1]{\mathbf {#1}}
%\newcommand{\vrv}[1]{\boldmath  {#1}  \unboldmath} 
%\RequirePackage{amsopn}
%\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\savesymbol{iint}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\restoresymbol{TXF}{iint}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeindex
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post an example we can compile to reproduce the errors i.e. with a document bit - not just the preamble. And don't include packages which don't affect the error. The errors mean that you are trying to define new commands with the same names as existing commands. This is probably because your preamble is a mess and you are loading the same packages twice, packages you don't need and incompatible packages. Never load a package more than once - especially with different options. And never load `epsfig` at all. It is obsolete. `hyperref` should be one of the last packages loaded.

Answer (score 4):

The errors mean that you are trying to define new commands with the same names as existing commands.

This is probably because your preamble is a mess and you are loading the same packages twice, packages you don't need and incompatible packages.

Never load a package more than once - especially with different options.

And never load `epsfig` at all. It is obsolete.

`hyperref` should be one of the last packages loaded.

The instructions say to use pdfLaTeX for compilation. If so, do not tell `graphicx` you want the `dvips` driver. Mostly, it will auto-detect the correct driver anyway.

The following compiles without errors:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,american]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,includeall,
            vmargin={1in,1in},
            hmargin={1.5in,0.375in}
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\savesymbol{iint}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\restoresymbol{TXF}{iint}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            colorlinks=true,
            pdfpagemode=UseNone,
            urlcolor=blue,
            bookmarks=true,
            backref=page,
            ]{hyperref}

% It would be better to use setspace here...
% Use only one of the following:
%   linespread effects math mode, openup does not.
%\linespread{1.6}    % 1.3 = line and a half spacing; 1.6 = double spaced
\openup4\jot        % 1 = single; 2.5 = line and half; 4 = double

\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.2ex plus 1ex minus 0.5ex}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The order of packages conflicts: Your document was like this

```
\usepackage{cases}
%\documentstyle[a4paper]{article}
:
:
:
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

And the correct order was pointed out by the previous answer as this

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
:
:
\usepackage{cases}
```